# Parlance or discourse

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

A negative aspect of the increased dominance of Big Business in the United States is that political ________ might come to center on economic matters, ignoring the larger requirements of civil society. Such society would have lost its perspective, **seeing what should be a means to an end--business--as an end in itself**; this might lead to excessive competitiveness, individualism, materialism, and _______ in society.

1. a. parlance
   b. discourse
   c. bombast
2. a. impassivity
   b. cupidity
   c. narcissism

Hi! experts. The answer to the blanks is given (discourse, cupidity) in book source: [https://www.amazon.com/Barrons-GRE-Verbal-Workbook-2nd/dp/143800379X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143800379X) 1

If I take parlance and narcissism what will be wrong, can you please explain?
And what does the bold part mean?

Answer (score 2):

Parlance [usually refers to a way of speaking](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parlance), for example "in common parlance" meaning "in everyday speech". 'Discourse' here refers to the act of discussion and the content of such a discussion, whereas 'parlance' would be used to refer to the use of specific words or phrases. It's the range of topics that discussion might cover that's relevant in that extract, so 'discourse' is used.

I don't know why narcissism wouldn't work in that context. It doesn't seem wrong to me, but possibly narcissism is a personal fault that can't be applied to society as a whole.

Comment: The Merriam-Webster dictionary says parlance also means debate or parley....so confusion arising...

Comment: @Richard there's not much chance of confusion. Merriam-Webster online gives examples of the use of the word, all with the "way of speaking" meaning of the word. I have never come across parlance to mean discourse - it might appear more in American English but I think it's just antiquated.

Comment: You mentioned the example "in common parlance" meaning "in everyday speech". Now, if I mentioned an example that "he gave a speech in lecture theater last week", what is to say to differentiate between the word 'speech' mentioned in your example and mine?

Comment: “Narcissism” works fine there.  The argument for “cupidity” is that the theme is “economic matters” and “greed” is therefore more relevant than narcissism.  “Parlance” feels weird though for the reason JamesK gives.  Worse than both imo is the phrase “might come to center on” both because it’s verbose and ambiguous: it took me a moment to parse because I read “center” at first as “political center”, since I’d just read the word “political.” This is not writing you should emulate.

Answer (score 2):

"Political discourse" is a collocation. Those two words are often used together (you can't work that out, you just have to know it)

"Cupidity" means "greed for money" which fits better with the topic of "the dominance of big business"

This testing if you know the meaning of the words and can choose the word with the most appropriate meaning.  The level is super high.  Most native speakers with university level education would have difficulty with "cupidity". My spell-checker thinks it is a error for "stupidity". I can't find any actual use, except as a joke, (playing on the similarity to "cupid" and ignoring the "actual" meaning)

To parse the bold part, look at this punctuation

> Seeing what should be a means-to-an-end (business) as an end in itself.

The word "business" is put between dashes — business — To indicate that it is an insertion.  It is just clarifying that the thing that should be a means-to-an-end  is "business".

I assume you understand "means-to-an-end" and "end in itself". If not, this exercise is at a significantly higher level than you are.

Comment: some quotations with it here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cupidity

Comment: Moby Dick and Lawrence Durrell....

Comment: can you explain what the bold part of the sentence means?